# Standard implementation of 2 dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, boost, std

I need to store some 2 dimensional array of data, the dimensions are fixed and known at runtime. Is there a 2D equivalent of the `array<T>` template  (either in std libraries or boost)?

Comment: Do you mean compile time instead of runtime?

Comment: An array of arrays? `std::array<std::array<int, COLS>, ROWS> table;`

Answer (score 2):

Google: [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <cassert>

int 
main () {
  // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
  typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

  // Assign values to the elements
  int values = 0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        A[i][j][k] = values++;

  // Verify values
  int verify = 0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        assert(A[i][j][k] == verify++);

  return 0;
}
```